# Chart.js - Custom interaction mode - evaluateInteractionItems() like nearest mode

Tags: chart.js

I have a customInteractionMode() like this:

```js
Interaction.modes.customInteractionMode = function (chart, e, options, useFinalPosition) {
  const position = getRelativePosition(e, chart);
  Interaction.evaluateInteractionItems(
    chart,
    'xy',
    position,
    (element, datasetIndex, index) => {
      if (element.inRange(position.x, position.y, useFinalPosition)) {...}
    },
    true
  )
}
```

How should I write handler() to get the same result with chart option below? my condition above not work

```js
options: {
  interaction: {
    mode: 'nearest',
    axis: 'xy',
    interest: true
  },
}
```